# Replacing boost with std implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std

What is the correct way to replace this:

```
std::ostringstream buf;
std::for_each(bd.begin(), bd.end(), buf << boost::lambda::constant("&nbsp;") << boost::lambda::_1);
```

With an implementation that doesn't use boost?  This is what I've tried:

```
std::string backspace("&nbps;");
std::ostringstream buf;        
std::for_each(bd.begin(), bd.end(), buf << backspace << std::placeholders::_1);
```

The second '<<' is underlined in red and I get the error message:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Ph<1>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::lambda` is a marvellous monstrosity that kind of backported lambdas to C++03. The equivalent to your code is:

```
std::ostringstream buf;
std::for_each(bd.begin(), bd.end(), [&](auto const &v) { buf << "&nbsp;" << v; });
```

... or even:

```
std::ostringstream buf;
for(auto const &v : bd)
    buf << "&nbsp;" << v;
```

Comment: Tried the first suggestion, get: error C3533: 'const auto &': a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'

Comment: @SPlatten Prior to C++14 `auto` lambdas weren't a thing.  Just use the concrete type of whatever is stored in `bd` instead.

Comment: or `typename decltype(bd)::const_reference v`