# Conversion of boost placeholders with arithmetic to std

Tags: c++, boost, std, placeholder

I am working on converting a C++ project which used boost and placeholders to transform a map the existing logic was:

```
inline const std::vector<uint32_t> average(const std::pair<uint16_t, std::vector<uint32_t> >& left,
                                           const std::pair<uint16_t, std::vector<uint32_t> >& right)
{
    // Ejector rates should be symmetrical
    assert(left.second.size() == right.second.size());
    std::vector<uint32_t> result;
    result.reserve(left.second.size());
    namespace bl = boost::lambda;
    // Walk both, do funny thing with each element in turn. Stuff into result.
    std::transform(left.second.begin(), left.second.end(), right.second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), (bl::_1 + bl::_2) / 2);
    return result;
}
```

I want to replace the boost references with std:

```
inline const std::vector<uint32_t> average(const std::pair<uint16_t, std::vector<uint32_t> >& left,
                                           const std::pair<uint16_t, std::vector<uint32_t> >& right)
{
    // Ejector rates should be symmetrical
    assert(left.second.size() == right.second.size());
    std::vector<uint32_t> result;
    result.reserve(left.second.size());
    namespace bl = boost::lambda;
    // Walk both, do funny thing with each element in turn. Stuff into result.
    std::transform(left.second.begin(), left.second.end(), right.second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result),
        (std::placeholders::_1 + std::placeholders::_2) / 2);
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error C2784: 'std::_Deque_const_iterator<_Mydeque> std::operator +(_Deque_const_iterator<_Mydeque>::difference_type,std::_Deque_const_iterator<_Mydeque>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Deque_const_iterator<_Mydeque>' from 'std::_Ph<2>'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\deque(555) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
```

On the line which contains:

```
(std::placeholders::_1 + std::placeholders::_2) / 2);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Per the same replacement logic as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63774109/3233393), that'd be `[&](uint32_t const lhs, uint32_t const rhs) { return (lhs + rhs) / 2; }`.

Comment: @JeJo indeed I don't. Just a habit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a lambda.
In general case you can use `const auto refs` to avoid coping of parameters:

```
std::transform(left.second.begin(), left.second.end(), right.second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), [] (auto const &a, auto const &b) { return (a+b)/2; });
```

In case of small numeric types like `int` you can pass them by value and use just `const auto` or specify the type explicitly:

```
std::transform(left.second.begin(), left.second.end(), right.second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), [] (uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return (a+b)/2; });
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! Was already editing my answer to show this case))) But thanks to your comment I rechecked and edited out some ambiguous terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda.

```
std::transform(left.second.begin(), left.second.end(), right.second.begin(), std::back_inserter(result),
        [](auto a, auto b){ return (a + b) / 2; });
```